# Using v-model with a prop on VUE.JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to use a data coming from a prop with v-model, the following code works, but with a warning.

```
<template>
<div>
       <b-form-input v-model="value" @change="postPost()"></b-form-input>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        props: {
            value: String
        },
        methods: {
            postPost() {
                axios.put('/trajectory/inclination', {
                    body: this.value
                })
                    .then(response => {
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The warning says:

**"Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"**

So I changed and now I'm using a data as the warning says.

```
<template>
<div>
       <b-form-input v-model="_value" @change="postPost()"></b-form-input>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        props: {
            value: String
        },
        data() {
            return {
                _value: this.value
            }
        },
        methods: {
            postPost() {
                axios.put('/trajectory/inclination', {
                    body: this._value
                })
                    .then(response => {
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

So now the code it's not working and the warning says:

**"Property or method "_value" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option"**

Any idea how to fix the first code to suppress the warning? (or some idea on how to fix the second code?)

Obs.: b-form-input it's not my componente, this is the Textual Input from Boostrap-Vue ([Doc for b-form-input](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input/))

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bert addresses your direct issue, but I think you should also know that your approach is a bit off. Since ultimately you are sending the new value to `postPost`, you don't really need to modify your local copy. Use the `event` object that is sent to the `change` handler to get the current value from the input.

Instead of `v-model`, just use `:value`, and don't include the invocation parentheses when specifying the `change` handler.

```
<template>
<div>
       <b-form-input :value="value" @change="postPost"></b-form-input>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        props: {
            value: String
        },
        methods: {
            postPost(event) {
                axios.put('/trajectory/inclination', {
                    body: event.target.value
                })
                    .then(response => {
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think your approach is a good one for getting the modified value. I would like to add something that I found If someone wants to change the value from the "prop" (like a two-way binding) the correct approach will be using the modifier sync [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier) and not the v-model

Comment: `.sync` is very similar to [`v-model` for components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model). You can use either one. `v-model` is specifically for `value` props, while `.sync` can be used with a prop of any name.

Comment: To help anybody, I was facing the same issue. I just changed my var that was inside v-model="" from props array to data.

Answer (score 46):

Answer is from https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7434

Props are read-only, but you are trying to change its value with v-model. In this case, if you change the input value, the prop is not modified and the value is restored on the next update.

Use a data property or a computed setter instead:

```
computed: {
  propModel: {
    get () { return this.prop },
    set (value) { this.$emit('update:prop', value) },
  },
},
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Comment: Also didn't Vue2 say that best practise one shouldn't be using $emit?

Comment: what an awful reply, just copy-pase from a github issue. how to use this in a class-based component? what is a data property?

Comment: @Phil for using computed in class component look at the [docs](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#computed-properties)

Answer (score 10):

_ prefixed properties are [reserved](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) for Vue's internal properties.

> Properties that start with _ or $ will not be proxied on the Vue
> instance because they may conflict with Vue’s internal properties and
> API methods.

Try changing **_value** to something that doesn't start with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks :) I found it in the API docs and added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for help Bert, changing the variable name makes it work like a charm. But as Roy mentioned in his answer maybe my approach using local variables was a bit off and as this question will be available for others maybe will be best for them to follow the other approach.

Answer (score 10):

One general workaround is to introduce a data-variable and watch the props to update-variable. This is quite subtle and so easy to get wrong so here's an example with a Vuetify modal using `v-model` (the same technique, in theory, should work with `<input>` and others):

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="isVisible" max-width="500px" persistent>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Blablabla',
  props: {
    visible: { type: Boolean, required: true }
  },
  data() {
    isVisible: false
  },
  watch: {
    // `visible(value) => this.isVisible = value` could work too
    visible() {
      this.isVisible = this.$props.visible
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

The official Vue docs shows how to use `v-model` on a custom component: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

**TL;DR:**

You simply need to have a specifically named `value` prop, and emit an `input` event which the `v-model` when you instantiate the component maps for you.

More info on how this works on the link above.

```html
<template>
  <input
    type="text"
    :value="value"
    @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Input",
  props: {
    value: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<Input v-model="searchText"></Input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Point your input v-model directive to a data property named `value_` (or any other name not starting with prefixes `_` or `$` which are reserved by Vue). Set the data property's default value to `null`. Then, add a method `getValue()` which will set property `value_` based on your `value` prop's value. Finally, call `getValue()` in Vue's `created()` lifecycle hook. Like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-input v-model="value_" @change="postPost()">
    </b-form-input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      value_: null
    }),
    props: {
      value: String
    },
    methods: {
      postPost() {
        axios.put('/trajectory/inclination', {
          body: this.value_
        })
        .then(response => {
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
        })
      },
      getValue() {
        this.value_ = this.value;
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getValue()
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data like below.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-bind:value="value" v-on:input="dValue= $event.target.value" />
</template>
        
 <script>
 export default {
  props: ["value"],
  data: function () {
    return {
      dValue: this.value,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    alertValue() {
     alert("Current Value" + this.dValue);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```