# Initialize v-model using props?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a Vue component that uses v-model. The initial value of the v-model will eventually come from a parent component or data store. The first step I'm trying to get working is to initialize the v-model with a property. I've tried the following without success:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea
      v-model="text"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: { initialValue: String },
  data() {
    return {
      text: this.props ? this.props.initialValue : 'This is a test'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And using it from a parent as follows:

```
<MyComponent initialValue="Hello World" />
```

The component displays 'This is a test' instead of 'Hello World' as I'd like. What is the proper way to initialize a component that is using a v-model?

**EDIT**

I've abandoned v-model for now and come up with this approach... but it doesn't feel very "Vue-ly".. I'm essentially tapping into implementation details of the textarea (eve.srcElement.value.length), when I feel like I should be tapping into a domain object... is there a better way to do this? Note, in the textChange event I'll eventually emit notifications for other components.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea
      :value="initialValue"
      @change="textChange"
      @keyup="textChange"
      placeholder="Type your text here"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: { initialValue: String },
  methods: {
    textChange: function(evt) {
      console.log('Length: ' + evt.srcElement.value.length)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using v-model with a prop on VUE.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164374/using-v-model-with-a-prop-on-vue-js)

Comment: I've edited my question. From what I can tell the solutions in the linked article do not exactly pertain to my question.

Answer (score 2):

`v-model` leverages the `value` prop. You'll need to emit the `input` event to then update the value in the parent.

**MyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value']
}
</script>
```

**Parent.vue**

```
<MyComponent v-model="val"/>
```

See [Using v-model on Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) for more details.

Comment: I don't understand the Parent.vue v-model="val". Can you explain this part?

Comment: `val` would be a data property in your parent component, i.e. `data: () => ({ val: 'foo' })`

Comment: I tried this but the performance isn't great... emitting that event and data every keypress is pretty heavy.

Comment: That's expected behavior. Consider using [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) - or implementing the function yourself -  to limit the number of events.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you can add a default value for the props that will be
  displayed when the props are not set.
- Secondly, with the help of the **mounted** or **created** [lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks), you can
  put the value "initialValue" in "text".

For your example, this is the simplest and most effective way. Depending on the task, this decision may no longer be relevant.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="text"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      initialValue: {
        type: String,
        default: 'This is a test',
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        text: '',
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.text = this.initialValue;
    },
  };
</script>
```