# Is it possible to use a prop as a v-model value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Is it possible to use the value of a prop as the input's v-model?

I normally do the following when creating an input:

```js
<template>
    <form>
        <input v-model="form.email" type="email"/>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                email: '',
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But now I'm trying to achieve the following where this.myProp is used within the v-model without being displayed as a string on the input:

```js
<template>
    <form>
        <input v-model="this.myProp" type="email"/>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['myProp'] // myProp = form.email for example (to be handled in a parent component)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is this solves your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164374/using-v-model-with-a-prop-on-vue-js

Comment: Never a good idea to mutate `props`. check [prop doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#mutating-object-array-props). if you want to modify data pass them to `computed property` and use it on `v-model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but while using it in parent component. In child component you need to extract `value` and `@input` instead of using `v-model` (v-model is shortcut for `value=""` and `@input`) Here is an example of input with label, error and hint in Vue 3 composition API.

**BaseInput.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
        <label>{{ label }}</label>
        <input v-bind="$attrs" :placeholder="label" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
        <span v-for="item of errors" class="text-red-400">{{ item.value }}</span>
        <span v-if="hint" class="text-sm">{{ hint }}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({ label: String, modelValue: String | Number, errors: Array, hint: String })
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

Using `v-bind="$attrs"` you target where attributes like `type="email"` need to be applied in child component. If you don't do it, it will be added to the top level DOM element. In above scenario `<div>`.

**ParentComponent.vue**

```js
<BaseInput type="email" v-model="formData.email" :label="Email" :errors="formErrors.email"/>
```